# How to generate aws cloudfront url through Spring Rest api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, spring-rest

My requirement is that, I want to upload a file into AWS S3 bucket through Spring REST api. This api should first generate a Cloudfront url and upload the file using the url generated and finally in the response I should get the complete filepath : cloudfront-url/filename.
Please let me know the steps and configuration required to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @user2031395, have you been able to solve this.If yes please provide the answer here. As I too want to learn how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If the server uploads the file from client to s3, it will create unnecessary overhead on the server.  Better approach is the return pre-signed URL to client (browser) and it directly uploads to S3.

See details on how to do it [here](https://blog.frugalops.com/quick-tutorial-to-integrate-amazon-s3-presigned-url/).

If that bucket is configured for cloudfront then the cloudfront url can be used directly.

See details [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/) for setting up cloudfront for s3.